# Using web service asp.net on client side

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jakarta-ee

I created a web service asp.net and I tested it in the Visual Studio Development Server. In that server I can choose the function that i want, enter the parameter, and what I have in result is correct. 
On the client side, I have got a Java EE application. My problem is, I don't know how to transmit the parameter with the URL. 
I tried something like this : `http://localhost:64378/WebSite3/Service.asmx/EchoWithGet?s=7458` or like this : `http://localhost:64378/WebSite3/Service.asmx?op=EchoWithGet&s=7458`
None of them works.
So my question is, how can I use the "EchoWithGet" function with the parameter s ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your service is called `Service.asmx`, i assume you created a SOAP-based web service. Use the WSDL document from the Service (http://localhost:64378/WebSite3/Service.asmx?WSDL) to create a proxy client for your Java EE application (have a look [here](http://teaching.cs.uml.edu/~heines/tools/JRun4/docs/html/Programmers_Guide/ws_wsdl5.html) on that subject).

If you just want a test for your service in browser you can use one of the many clients available. Firefox has a nice [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/soa-client/).

Comment: Thanks, I will watch your link